# Configuring openldap/PHP LDAP against "signed" LDAP connections with Active Directory

Tags: linux, ldap, linux-networking, windows, php

This may sound like a stupid question, and maybe it's already been answered, but I can't find a definitive answer anywhere, so I thought I'd ask.

When someone enables "Domain controller: LDAP server signing requirements" within Group Policy on Windows Server, what is the requirement on the Linux end of things to support that? I've tried searching MSDN, here, and general Googling, but nothing seems to help. We're running both Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and CentOS 6.6, with OpenLDAP and PHP 5.5.x in place.

Any Windows Server/Linux expertise in LDAP would be greatly appreciated.